# Missing file or directory after Installshield installation

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, installshield

I'm a web developer building a windows console app for the first time in years.  It reads a database, uses ClosedXML to create an Excel workbook, then mails the workbook.

App runs fine on my laptop.  I'm using `Installshield LE with VS2015`. I pointed the "Add Files" dialog to my `bin\Release` directory, and it got all my .DLLS, .XML, .EXE, etc.  I copied the `DiskImages\DISK1` directory to my server. It installs without error on my server, but when I RDP and execute from its shortcut, I get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null`.

I can't tell where the error is popping, but I suspect that since I get a lot of string values from the App.config file, it can't find that file, so it passes an empty string to a MailAddress constructor. Shouldn't app.config be included as part of the .EXE when I "Add Files" in IS?

Also on the "Add Folders" dialog I added a folder named "Documents", but it is nowhere to be found on the server file system.  I must be configuring the setup wrong, but I don't know how.

Comment: You'll need to add the app.config to the installer as well. An app.config is not part of the .exe.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb:  That was it, thanks very much. If you add your comment to an answer, I'll mark it "answered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.config is a separate file from the .exe.
You'll need to add the app.config to the installer as well.